# Add number of columns based on a value

Tags: vba, excel, loops, bulkinsert

Currently i have data as following in Excel:

```
USER    ||  COUNT   ||  REPEAT COUNT    ||  OTHER DETIALS IN THE ROW
a       ||  2       ||                  ||  ASD
s       ||  1       ||                  ||  SDF
d       ||  4       ||                  ||  DFG
f       ||  1       ||                  ||  FGH
d       ||  1       ||                  ||  GHJ
f       ||  1       ||                  ||  HKJ
```

I require the content in the row to be copy pasted to a newly inserted row based on "count" and insert - "repeat count"

output data should be as follows:

```
USER    ||  COUNT   ||  REPEAT COUNT    ||  OTHER DETIALS IN THE ROW
a       ||  2       ||  1               ||  ASD
a       ||  2       ||  2               ||  ASD
s       ||  1       ||                  ||  SDF
d       ||  4       ||  1               ||  DFG
d       ||  4       ||  2               ||  DFG
d       ||  4       ||  3               ||  DFG
d       ||  4       ||  4               ||  DFG
f       ||  1       ||                  ||  FGH
d       ||  1       ||                  ||  GHJ
f       ||  1       ||                  ||  HKJ
```

Comment: Well, I **require** a pony. With a pink mane. And it has to be a girl princess pony. I will call her Spirit Cloud and we will ride in the sky forever.

Comment: In other words: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51045458/edit) your question to show us what you've tried and explain to us why it's not working the way you want, we will then be able to help you achieve your goal. but we won't do all the work for you.

Comment: A tip to prevent you from running into a trap. If you plan to insert (or delete) rows in a loop you must start from the bottom not from the top: Eg. `For i = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1` otherwise your loop counts wrong every time you insert a row.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. Update to your range where stated

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ConvertValuesToRows()
    Dim destRange As Range, rng As Range, srcRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, RowCount As Long

    ' Update this to your source range
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    End With

    With rng
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 2) > 1 Then
                RowCount = .Cells(i, 2) - 1
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, .Columns.Count)).Resize(RowCount).Insert shift:=xlDown

                Set srcRange = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, rng.Columns.Count))
                Set destRange = Range(srcRange, srcRange.Offset(RowCount, 0))

                srcRange.AutoFill Destination:=destRange, Type:=xlFillCopy
                .Cells(i, 3) = 1
                srcRange.Columns(3).AutoFill Destination:=destRange.Columns(3), Type:=xlFillSeries
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```